# jquery cms plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build an simple publishing tool in jquery. But i'm a bit confused, would love
to build it in an jquery plugin fashion. But jquery works on specific elements or objects.
So, how can I achieve an publishing tool that is "global" to its child objects.

My thought was creating a plugin applied to the window which should be the highest object.
So perhaps:

```
$(window).mypublishtool();
```

Then access functions within this plugin to find edit child elements within page.

I would appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks

Comment: ?! you can't use jQuery as a CMS...

Comment: No but I would like to use jquery to build a cms

Comment: You can't.  jQuery is a client-side JavaScript framework.  A CMS would require server-side programming like with Perl, PHP, etc.

Comment: You could write a CMS for the client-side that simply generates JSON to be digested by the server in whatever way the developer wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it soley using Jquery. Your best bet it to use it in conjunction with a server-side language; PHP, ASP.NET, Java, CGI-BIN, etc ...). If this does not help, please describe more on what your thoughts are and what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Here is a link to view more on what CMS's are and how complicated they actually are to build.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system